# Extending existing XSD and allow backward validation

Tags: xml, xsd

The goal is to create an XML schema that extends an existing XML schema such that the resulting instance documents can be validated with either the base XSD or the extension XSD.

Here is an example base XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:dx="dataxsd/1"
    targetNamespace="dataxsd/1"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

    <xs:complexType name="DataType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Start" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="End" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="Value" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xs:any namespace="##other" processContents="lax" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:integer"/>
        <xs:anyAttribute namespace="##other" processContents="lax"/>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:element name="Data" type="dx:DataType"></xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I would like to extend it to make a superset.   My initial approach was to use the xs:redefine functionality similar to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:dx="dataxsd/1"
    targetNamespace="dataxsd/1"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

    <xs:redefine schemaLocation="data.xsd">
        <xs:complexType name="DataType">
            <xs:complexContent>
                <xs:extension base="dx:DataType">
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="Status" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:extension>
            </xs:complexContent>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:redefine>
</xs:schema>
```

Using oXygen 14.1 both of these schemas validate successfully.

An instance document containing the extended schema  will not validate against the non-extended schema due to the xs:any namespace only allowing "##other", the xs:redefine requires that the extensions be in the same namespace.

It is undesirable to change the base schema, but I experimented with changing it to set the xs:any namespace restriction to "##any" the XSD itself will not validate, the Xerces complaint is:

```
cos-nonambig: "dataxsd/1":Start and WC[##any] (or elements from their substitution group) violate "Unique Particle Attribution". During validation against this schema, ambiguity would be created for those two particles.
```

I also tried the XML Schema 1.1 xs:override functionality because the xs:redefine is now designated deprecated in 1.1, but I could never get this to validate correctly and the support seems to be in very early stages.

Is there any way to accomplish the goal of extending the original, base schema and allowing instance documents containing the extension(s) to validate with the base, non-extended schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relaxing the namespace-restriction creates an ambiguity between matching a `<xd:Start>` element as the `<xs:element name="Start"/>`-rule, or skipping them all and matching it as the `<xs:any />` rule. The same is also true for the other pre-defined elements.

In Regex, you would use a greedy quantifier in this case, but the XSD-language does not make  distinction between [greedy and lazy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regex#Lazy_quantification).

As it stands, there are two ways to solve it:

- Pick another namespace in the second file.
- Make the last defined element in the first file required, and non-repeatable: `minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"`. Maybe wrapping the values in a `<xd:Values>`-element.

---

**Read more:**

- [Creating Extensible Content Models](http://www.xfront.com/ExtensibleContentModels.html)

Comment: Thanks Markus.  Another namespace cannot be used with a 'redefine' that I know of, also using 'import' or 'include' means that an existing schema type cannot be extended.  Unfortunately I cannot use the second idea of making the last defined element required and non-repeatable since this is across many elements and many include only optional elements necessarily.